# Rip tool not considering the mouse direction

Tags: edit-mode

I'm new to blender and im trying to use rip tool but it's not working properly. No matter where the mouse cursor is, it's always ripping in the same side.

This is the vertices i want to rip

[image]

And the result i get every time i rip is this, but i want the rip to happen on the other direction.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rip **depends on your mouse position**. So if you want to rip off other side, you should place your cursor on the right side of your edge.

Example:
[image: https://i.imgur.com/xkSMJdQ.gif]

Comment: Worked now, thanks